# Model steps of a task in database

Tags: database, database-design, google-cloud-datastore

I'm developing a web application with Google App Engine. However, the question is not specific to this platform, it's more database related and conceptual.

I have a model called `task` right now. And there should be several steps to accomplish a task. I'm thinking about creating another model called `step`. A user can create as many steps as they want and can delete a certain step, add a step between two steps or exchange two steps. It's easy to see this is a one(`task`)-to-many(`step`) relationship. But the problem is the relationship between steps(the ordering of them mostly) would need a lot of work if I design it simply this way.

For example, I have a task called 'Go see a movie' and a user may first creates three steps for this task. 1. search for a good movie online 2.buy the ticket 3.leave home on time

Now let's say the model `step` has a property called `order` as an int, and a `description`. If the user wants to delete the first step, the `order` of the second and the third will have to change too. This seems very expensive and troublesome. And it would not be easy if the user wants to exchange two steps.

So is there a better way to model this? Maybe there are some features of the database fit this situation?

Comment: this is a linked list.  also consider a 'step' is just another task - no need to differentiate.

Comment: @Randy Yeah, it's a linked list. 'Task' might not be the right word for what I'm trying to model, should be replaced by 'goal'.